# How to rename many columns in R

Tags: r

I have a messy data in this format

```
Brand<–c("Brand1","Brand2","Brand3")
Sold_quantity_this_week<–c(5,8,17)
Sold_dollar_amount_this_week<–c(150,350,780)
Sold_quantity_minus_1_week<–c(7,6,8)
Sold_dollar_amount_minus_1_week<–c(200,300,350)

Sold_quantity_minus_2_week<–c(8,9,10)
Sold_dollar_amount_minus_2_week<–c(220,400,420)

| Brand  | Sold quantity(this week) | Sold $amount(this week) | Sold quantity(-1 week) | Sold $amount(-1 week) | Sold quantity(-2 week) | Sold $amount(-2 week) |
|--------|--------------------------|-------------------------|------------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
| Brand1 | 5                        | 150                     | 7                      | 200                   | 8                      | 220                   |
| Brand2 | 8                        | 350                     | 6                      | 300                   | 9                      | 400                   |
| Brand3 | 17                       | 780                     | 8                      | 350                   | 10                     | 420                   |
|        |                          |                         |                        |                       |                        |                       |
```

This is just a  simple case of my problem. I have weekly sales data with 35 weeks. I want to represent the columns in date format in order to rename all the columns with a few lines of code. 
My goal is to set i column name as Date and the i+2 would be i column -7 to see the values for the previous weeks. Then the names of the columns coerce again back  as character,add "quantity" to the name,(do the same for dollar amount) and then to represent the data  in long format.
How can I do it?

```
names(data)[2] <-"26.08.2018"
for(i in seq(2,72,2)){
  names(data)[,i+2]=names(data)[,i]-7
}
```

My code here is not working maybe because it is not possible to have Date format column names, I guess.However I do not want to rename all the names manually then make long format data. Can you please suggest possible solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Column names  must be `character` class.

Comment: `names(data)` is a 1-dimensional vector, but you're indexing it with `[, columns]` as if it had 2 dimensions. And you're also treating the names as if you can do math on them. `names(data)[i+2] = names(data)[i]-7` is syntactically correct (getting rid of the commas), but you still have a problem because `"26.08.2018" - 7` is meaningless to R.

Comment: You can try `x = as.Date("26.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y") - 7, which will give you a Date class result `"2018-08-19"`, which you could then `format(x, "%d.%m.%Y")` to get back to your `dd.mm.yyyy` format.

Comment: It will probably be easier for you if you go with longer format. Columns for Brand,  Week, Qty, Amt. Brand and Week data will be duplicated, but this will allow your program to easily adapt if there are more or fewer weeks. And it is much easier to perform date arithmetic. You can always convert it back to wider format if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Here how I solved this problem. First I created a vector 

`x <-"26.08.2018"
x<- as.Date(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
x <- append(x,seq(x,by=-7,length.out = 36))
x <- x[-1]
x <- rep(x, each=2)
x<- paste0(x, c('.X',".Y"))      
colnames(my_data) <- c("Brand",x)`
Then change the date to a  long format .